# How to display data from the rows in page header?

Tags: crystal-reports

I've a data source connected to my Crystal Reports for Enterprise which hat this structure:

```
--------------------------------------
| OrderNo | Level | Customer | Price |
|=========|=======|==========|=======|
| 1       | 1     | Cus_A    | 70.00 |
| 2       | 1     | Cus_A    | 78.30 |
| 3       | 2     | Cus_B    | 24.50 |
| 4       | 2     | Cus_B    | 14.50 |
| 5       | 2     | Cus_B    | 17.50 |
--------------------------------------
```

Now I need for my page header the customer where Level is 1 and 2 so it looks like that:

```
 I. Cus_A
II. Cus_B
```

Has anybody an idea how to get this values of Customer in two variables without using a subreport for calculating the variables?

Thanks!

Comment: If its in page header then you need to use sub report

Comment: Thank you, I've tried it but I don't get results in my main report. I've a formular in my report header to initialize the vars `Shared StringVar OE_R2;`.After that where is my subreport in the report header with one formula in the body to calc my variables with `Shared StringVar OE_R2; OE_R2 := {SBEDMP01_2016_Q001.SBCHOERE\SBCHOERE - Medium Text}`. But getting the value in page header is not possible. But why?

Comment: Don't use any shared variables just display data in sub report and place the sub report in page header